# What are default user account and password of Fedora 31 Cloud Base Image for OpenStack?

Tags: fedora, cloud

I download Fedora Cloud Base image for Openstack image from here:
https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/31/Cloud/x86_64/images/Fedora-Cloud-Base-31-1.9.x86_64.qcow2

Then create a virtual machine on OpenStack based on this image.

In the console of this virtual machine, it shows,

```
Fedora 31 (Cloud Edition)
Kernel 5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64 on an x86_64 (tty1)

Localhost login:
```

My question is, what are the default user account and password here to login?

BTW, I have tried to change the password of root as described in the following link, but it doesn't work.
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?297501-How-can-i-change-lost-root-password-in-F20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenStack article
[Get images](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/obtain-images.html),
has this information:

> The simplest way to obtain a virtual machine image that works with OpenStack is to download one that someone else has already created. Most of the images contain the cloud-init package to support the SSH key pair and user data injection. Because many of the images disable SSH password authentication by default, boot the image with an injected key pair. You can SSH into the instance with the private key and default login account. See
>   [Configure access and security for instances](https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/user/configure-access-and-security-for-instances.html)
>   for more information on how to create and inject key pairs with OpenStack.

It also says:

> Note
>
> In a Fedora cloud image, the login account is **fedora**.

I would try user `fedora` and password `fedora`, but if this doesn't work,
some images are created so that password login is not possible,
and you will need to follow the above link for
using a keypair to login.

Comment: user ```fedora``` and password ```fedora``` does not work.

Comment: For AWS: Tried to connect to Fedora 31 cloud an AWS using the usual user `fedora` and, as usual, the public key id procedure: `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`. Tried a few other usernames. NOPE! Confused, tested with Fedora 30 cloud and always-has-been-so username `fedora` - A-OK No problem there! There is some problem with Fedora Cloud 31, maybe?

Comment: Please don't' downvote answer from many years ago.

Answer (score 4):

use guestfs-tools

```
virt-customize -a Fedora-Cloud-Base-35-1.2.x86_64.qcow2 --root-password password:xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable login you can set user-data to:

```
#cloud-config
password: my_desired_password
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

Here's what I do to run images locally with KVM/VirtualMachineManager.

```
# cat meta-data 
instance-id: iid-something-whatwever
local-hostname: desired-hostname

# cat user-data 
#cloud-config
password: my_desired_password
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True

# genisoimage -output seed.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock user-data meta-data
```

Then you use `seed.iso` as a CDROM. Surely there must be a way to add ssh key with user-data but I haven't investigated that yet.